# React Native - Firebase content only loading on hot reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm running a React Native project on expo, and I'm pulling data from a Firestore database. When the page loads, the container is empty but if the page hot-reloads all the data shows up as expected. The get/set functions are exported from a Database file and imported in the relevant places. I don't think the problem comes from the Database functions

```
  const [dataarray,setDataArray]=useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    
    async function getData(){

      await fetchFirebaseData();
    }
    getData();
  },[])

  const fetchFirebaseData=async()=>{
      let data = await functionImportedFromDatabaseFile();
      functionImportedFromDatabaseFile().then(setDataArray(data));
    }

  return(

    <View >

      {dataarray.map((data, index)=>(
        
       ...///Render the data here

    ))}




  )
}
```

Comment: You don't need the 2nd line in `fetchFirebaseData()`. Have you tried just `setDataArray(data)` after the `let data` line?

Comment: Doing that stops it from loading the data at all

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue due to the frontend loading before the data is called. Something simple you could do would be to wrap the frontend in an activity monitor so it only shows once the data is fetched for the first time. Additionally you could also create another useState variable like this:

```
const [called, setCalled] = useState(false);
```

Then once the data is fetched, I set this value to true. Then at the end of my useEffect I added called in the square brackets as a listener.

What this does is refreshes the frontend once that variable changes. I hope this kind of helps